# Como acessar o método isComplete() do mat-date-range-picker no template?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Estou tentando acessar o método `isComplete()` do [mat-date-range-picker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api) no meu template:

You should select the range date


Porém estou recebendo este erro:

> error TS2339: Property 'isComplete' does not exist on type
> 'MatDateRangePicker

Segundo a documentação o método isComplete() checa se a seleção atual foi completada (se foi selecionado data inicial e data final).

Como acessar esse método no meu template?

Comment: O certo seria você chamar esse metodo toda vez que o valor da data muda e setar uma propriedade e checar essa propriedade no seu template

Comment: segundo a documentação este método já não faz exatamente isso?

Comment: no angular não se deve usar metodos como valores no template

Comment: como assim? nesse caso eu usaria no *ngIf, dependendo do valor ele renderizaria ou não

Comment: voce setar o valor do metodo em uma propriedade e fazer o ngif baseado nessa proprieddade

Comment: qual seria sua sugestão? atribuir pra uma variável? criar um pipe?

Comment: atribuir para uma variavel exatamente